# Identifying Streaming Process chains

Tags: sap-basis, sap-bw

I want to check all the streaming Process chains we have in our system. I tried to check in `ST13` BW tools but streaming column is not there to identify.

Is there any way to find Streaming Process chains running in our system?

Answer (score 1):

You can use table RSPCCHAINATTR and filter on column STREAMING <> 'blank' to get a list of all PC that are streaming enable in your BW system.

cheers